# dotnet core limit memory usage

Tags: docker, .net-core

I'm trying to run dotnet core project in Kubernetes and I am wondering if there a way to limit memory usage **from dotnet core project itself** the same way we can set a limit for `jvm` projects.

I see there is an optional argument in Docker to set memory limit:

```
docker run --memory="198m" xxx
```

Also in Kubernetes yaml file, we can set memory limit as well:

```
resources:
  requests:
    # ~402 MB
    memory: "384Mi"
    cpu: "250m"
  limits:
    # ~1500MB
    memory: "1430Mi"
    cpu: "500m"
```

Comment: This isn't really a Kubernetes question.

Comment: @switchboard.op yes it's not really related to Kubernetes but I showed what I what tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using dotnet core 2.0.2 or higher I believe it respects Docker's cgroup limits by default.
So all good on `2.0.2+`. Just set the resource limits in K8S

https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/13895

Comment: I have seen this fail. Dealing with this at present - the .net core binary is not obeying memory limits of the machine it is on. WEther this is because K8S is not communicating the memory limit, or because of a bug in .net core, this answer sadly is not valid.

Comment: Have you filed an issue on https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr ?

Comment: its fixed in .net core 3 but AFAIK they are not planning on backporting it.